# Get promoted type

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

How to get the promoted types of two operands?

This might be useful for code like this:

```
template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
bool would_overflow_upon_addition (LHS lhs, RHS rhs) {
    return lhs > std::numeric_limits<promoted<LHS,RHS>::type>::max()-rhs;
}
```

Comment: As a result of a brainfart, I was actually looking for a solution to the wrong question, so I thought this might also happen to others. (see the revision history of another answer I've given: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12675321/revisions)

Comment: What's with the sudden surge of "blog post" questions? Yesterday everyone wanted to build a shell, today everyone is posting strawman questions...

Comment: @KerrekSB: It is monday. We are not on rev yet. Whereas sundays is when ppl dream. Any example for the shell thing?

Comment: Take a look at the questions in the past 36 hours... tons of "I'm writing my own shell" type stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) should be your answer:

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef std::common_type<LHS, RHS>::type ctype;
```

Comment: ... I actually have something like this in my personal codebase, and even called it this way, so facepalm. Is it semantically different from `decltype(lhs+rhs)`?

Comment: @phresnel: it's the same for the fundamental arithmetic types.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually simpler than one might think:

```
template <typename LHS, typename RHS>
bool would_overflow_upon_addition (LHS lhs, RHS rhs) {
    return lhs > std::numeric_limits<decltype(lhs+rhs)>::max()-rhs;
}
```

`decltype(X)` is not evaluated, just the static type of `X` is derived <sup>*</sup>

---

<sup>* So there won't happen "compile-time-overflows" or "compile-time-undefined-behaviours"</sup>